# How can I extract all values of a particular attribute within elements inside a JSON array in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, json, mysql-json

I've the below data stored in a column of MySQL table which is of "json" data type (MySQL v5.7.9)

```
[{"id": "26", "title": "similar1", "score": "0.97"}, {"id": "27", "title": "similar2", "score": "0.87"}, {"id": "28", "title": "similar2", "score": "0.87"}]
```

I need a MySQL query which will return me all the "title" values i.e. similar1, similar2 and similar3 and so on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use JSON_EXTRACT().

```
mysql> create table t ( j json );

mysql> insert into t set j = '[{"id": "26", "title": "similar1", "score": "0.97"}, {"id": "27", "title": "similar2", "score": "0.87"}, {"id": "28", "title": "similar2", "score": "0.87"}]';

mysql> select json_extract(j, '$[*].title') from t;
+--------------------------------------+
| json_extract(j, '$[*].title')        |
+--------------------------------------+
| ["similar1", "similar2", "similar2"] |
+--------------------------------------+
```

If you want to use JSON data in MySQL, you should read the docs on [Functions that Search JSON Values](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html), and learn to use the JSON search expressions.

Comment: Thanks a ton Bill, you saved my day. '$[*].title' is what I was looking for. I did go through the documentation, but wasn't able to figure out how to use it on JSON arrays

Comment: *Hey Bill,* remember what you told me not too long ago? ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- You got me! I am breaking my own rule. But at least this is not the 1000th time I've seen this question.

Comment: @BillKarwin Hehe, no worries Bill. There are exceptions ;-) but yeah, I caught you *lol!* - Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a database design issue. It seems that you're using a json column when you should really be using another table to store these results as individual columns.

Comment: My initial DB design did have all the values in multiple columns, but this is a one to many DB relationship I'm dealing it. So, if I start saving "id", "title" and "score" in separate columns, and they've a lot of multiple values, I'll end up saving them in too many rows

Answer (score 0):

you can query like below

```
create table testTableforus (datapoint json);
insert into testTableforus
values
 ('{"id": "26", "title": "similar1", "score": "0.97"}'), 
 ('{"id": "27", "title": "similar2", "score": "0.87"}'), 
 ('{"id": "28", "title": "similar2", "score": "0.87"}');

 select datapoint->"$.title" from testTableforus;

drop table testTableforus;
```

<kbd>[See working demo](http://rextester.com/GANP43961)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks bhai, but if you observe closely, I've all the data in a single record and not multiple rows. Basically my data is an array of JSON object, and not a single JSON object like you've demonstrated